# changing the bower install path for certain repositories only

Tags: javascript, polymer, bower, package-managers

I have been playing around with Bower and coincidentally also with Polymer.

you can download polymer elements via bower like:

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/iron-image
```

I'm guessing there's some repo that polymer knows to search in to find that file.

I would like to have anything from `PolymerElements/*` go to a folder called `web_components` rather than the `bower_components` folder, but I want everything else to still go to `bower_components` How can I achieve this?

I know I can tell everything to go to `web_components` by putting:

```
{
  "directory" : "web_components"
}
```

in my `.bowerrc`

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with the built-in tools/arguments provided by bower. You will need to come up with a custom script to handle component placement. Sounds like a good feature request to add to their github issues page.